# When discussing limits and continuity, it is sometimes written that if limit $f(x)= 0$, then by the limit definition $|f(x)| ≤ ε/2$. Why?

Tags: real-analysis, limits, analysis, continuity

I think I understand the limit by definition to some extent, but why $ε/2$? Why not $ε/3$ or $ε/4$? I fail to grasp the utility of dividing epsilon and I often encounter it in problems of limits and continuity. Any explanation is appreciated.

Comment: There is no difference: you can also put  $ε/3$
 or $ε/4$. Traditionally one puts either $\varepsilon/2$ or $\varepsilon$ small as desired.

Comment: It basically depends on what you're trying to prove, and generally the choice of what coefficient to use (or what power to put $\varepsilon$ at if powers are involved, but that's less frequent) is just to make the proof more "elegant" by the time you finish it.

Comment: @Sebastiano thank you for your reply. But, is that a rule? That if a limit is equal to zero then |f(x)|≤ε. In other words, is this applicable if the limit is equal to some other real number? What about infinity?

Comment: @BrunoB Is this applicable if limit f(x)=a, where a is different from zero? Thank you for your reply!

Comment: In that case you'll just go with $|f(x) - a| \leq \lambda\varepsilon$, with whatever $\lambda$ you wish to use.

Comment: When I was at university, I did not understand the reason because I sometimes had to put $\varepsilon/2$ when proving the limit theorem of a sum. All because when you make the addition required by the theorem the total sum is $\varepsilon/2+\varepsilon/2=\varepsilon$. It is just an elegance to have $\varepsilon$. You could also have in this theorem a total sum of $2\varepsilon$ which is the same as having $\varepsilon$.

Comment: @BrunoB I am agree with you totally.

Comment: In [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4360099/568204) I give about 12 equivalent conditions for limits. Which one happens to be more convenient for the task at hand varies from individual to individual and task to task.